# Vim - removing leading and trailing spaces in a function

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I am trying to remove leading and trailing spaces in a function but it does not work:

```
function Trim(s)
    echo ">>>".a:s."<<<"
    let ss = substitute(a:s, '\v^\s*([^\s]+)\s*$', '\1', '') 
    echo ">>>".ss."<<<"
endfunction
```

The regex `\s*([^\s]+)\s*` works ok on https://regex101.com/

Replacing * with + does not make any difference.

Testing:

```
: call Trim("   testing    ")
```

Output:

```
>>>   testing    <<<
>>>   testing    <<<
```

Also it seems to matter if I use double quotes versus single quotes in substitute function.

Where are the problems and how can they be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by your collection.

You should use `[^ ]` instead of `[^\s]`:

```
function! Trim(s)
    echo ">>>".a:s."<<<"
    let ss = substitute(a:s, '\v^\s*([^ ]+)\s*$', '\1', '') 
    echo ">>>".ss."<<<"
endfunction
```

This is because collections work on individual characters and `\s` is not an individual character; it's seen as `\` followed by `s`, which doesn't resolve to anything because `s` is not a special character that needs escaping.

If you want your collection to include both spaces and tabs, use this:

```
[^ \t]
[ \t]
```

where `\t` represents a tab.

Comment: So far for my *buggy* comment on `\s`, tx Romain. Note that this interpretation of a collection seems to be vim specific?! The only regex flavor I find using the same interpretation is POSIX.

Comment: That explains the problem very well. I also see that the solution does not work if enclosed in double quotes rather than single quotes. What's the reason? (According to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435586/should-i-use-single-or-double-quotes-in-my-vimrc-file , I expected double quotes to be required here).

Comment: Actually, in docs http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute%28%29 , double quotes are being used.

Comment: @mso - I was going to make a case about performance but testing both solutions, it seems that any performance differences are negligable.

Comment: Escaping is done differently when you use double quotes or single quotes. With double quotes, `\s` is a literal ``\`` followed by a literal `s` and you would need to add another ``\`` to force Vim to treat `\s` as a character class. This would make your pattern look like this: `"\\v^\\s*([^ ]+)\\s*$"`.

Answer (score 2):

As romainl explained, `[^\s]` means neither `\` nor `s`. The contrary of `\s` (i.e. anything but a space or a tab) would be `\S`.

Otherwise, here is another solution: in lh-vim-lib I've defined the following

```
function! lh#string#trim(string) abort
  return matchstr(a:string, '^\v\_s*\zs.{-}\ze\_s*$')
endfunction
```

Regarding the difference(s) between the various kinds of quote characters, see this Q/A on vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quoted-strings

Answer (score 1):

You are including what needs to be retained in your search/replace. Much easier is to just **look for what needs te be removed** and substitute that

```
:%s/\v(^\s+|\s+$)//g
```

**Breakdown**

```
%s             Start a global search/replace
\v             Use Very Magic 
(^\s+          search for leading spaces
|              or
\s+$)          search for trailing spaces
//g            remove all search results from entire line
```

Comment: This is all right but the question is why my code is not working? What is wrong with that code and how can that be corrected?

Comment: The search pattern `\v^\s*([^\s]+)\s*$` you are using does not return any result. If you insist on including what needs to be retained in your search, you are complicating things. You need to be aware of greedy search, of lines having no leading spaces and of lines not having trainling spaces.

Comment: `\s*` is for 0 or more leading or trailing spaces. I need to check re greedy search.

Comment: The `[^\s]+` in by itself seems buggy btw. It stops matching at the `s` from testing.

Comment: What is the solution, even though it may be complicated?

Comment: I can't readily find one using vim's regex intricaties. Your regex works using PHP's regex flavor so it's just a matter of finding what vim's regex engine care's to accept.

Comment: Vimgolf: `:%s/\s\+$//|%le`

Comment: @PeterRincker - lol, nice but it does depend on the indent setting.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers `:left` defaults to `0` so it will remove all leading space